# How to get all elements in a list in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, playwright

I have a page container having list of folders. I want to click them one by one. Attached is the screenshot of the page with page source. [image]

I have tried the below code:

```
   let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('document-container')

   for (let element of elements)
   {
    await  element.click();
   }
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`page.$$`](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.2.1&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=pageselector-1) to collect all instances of the `.document-container` elements as [element handles](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.2.1&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=class-elementhandle). **It runs** `document.querySelectorAll` **in the page's context.**

Then you are able to iterate the clicks with [`elementHandle.click`](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.2.1&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=elementhandleclickoptions) (as you've already tried it).

```js
const elHandleArray = await page.$$('.document-container')

for (const el of elHandleArray) {
  await el.click()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where have you initiated the current page, using puppeteer?
You gotta use `page.click(elementToClick);`.

Here, you are trying to get the elements inside the specified `div`. That means, you need to get the children of the specified container `div`.

To get all children of a HTML element,
You can always use `.children` property, which will return the array of elements inside another element. And will return an empty array, in case the parent element has no child.

In your code, you may try something like this:

```
let container = document.getElementByClassName('document-container');

let elements = container.children;

for(element in elements){
  element.click();
}
```

See if it works.

Comment: It is initiated in the start. I just want a solution using the attached screenshot page source. The div has class name="someContainier" . I want to get all of its elements.

Comment: Elements inside it?